# Kubernetes Dashborad is not opening

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

My Master node ip address is 192.168.56.101. there is no node connected to master yet.

```
master@kmaster:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
kmaster   Ready    master   125m   v1.15.1
master@kmaster:~$
```

When i deployed my kubernetes-dashborad using below command, why running IP Address of kubernetes-dashboard-5c8f9556c4-f2jpz is 192.168.189.6
Similarly the other pods has also different IP address.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta1/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

```
master@kmaster:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP               NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-7bd78b474d-r2bwg      1/1     Running   0          113m   192.168.189.2    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-dsgqt                             1/1     Running   0          113m   192.168.56.101   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-5c98db65d4-n2wml                      1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.189.3    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-5c98db65d4-v5qc8                      1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.189.1    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-kmaster                                  1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.56.101   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-kmaster                        1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.56.101   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-kmaster               1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.56.101   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-bgtmr                              1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.56.101   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-kmaster                        1/1     Running   0          114m   192.168.56.101   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-5c8f9556c4-f2jpz         1/1     Running   0          107m   192.168.189.6    kmaster   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-metrics-scraper-86456cdd8f-w45w2   1/1     Running   0          107m   192.168.189.4    kmaster   <none>           <none>
master@kmaster:~$
```

And also not able to access the kubernetes-dashboard UI. i am using the link
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.

and the link KubeDNS https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy is also not working.

but when trying to access Kubernetes master at https://192.168.56.101:6443 is working.

```
master@kmaster:~$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.56.101:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: When trying to reach https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy/ , showing  error " Error: 'EOF'
Trying to reach: 'http://192.168.189.1:53/' "

Comment: What kind of kubernetes cluster do you have? How is is installed?

Comment: I have installed ubuntu on Oracle VM machine. On top of that installing kubernetes.

Comment: How did you setup and configure kubernetes?

Comment: Install Docker with commands : 
# sudo su
# apt-get update 
# apt-get install -y docker.io

# apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl 
Then deployed Kubernetes cluster from the master’s machine by Running the following command:

kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.101 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16

Comment: Your physical network seems to be 192.168.56.0/24 while your calico overlay network 192.168.0.0/16 overlaps with this. I assume further that your service ip range might be configured in this range as well. This will probably lead to network problems and you should design for a setup with separated networks.

Comment: I suppose to access the Kubernetes Dashborad by following link

https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

After that i could see the Dashborad.

but not able to access the KubeDNS.

https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy/

Comment: Thanks for Replay. I will take care of calico overlay network by changing to 192.168.56.0/24. Can you please tell me why KubeDNS link is not working. Because of calico overlay network overlaps. I am getting below error when trying to access the KubeDNS.  https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy/   [ Error: 'EOF'
Trying to reach: 'http://192.168.189.3:53/' ]

Answer (score 1):

Solution (see comments): Don't mix your physical and overlay network ranges.

Accessing the KubeDNS is only possible with DNS as protocol, not HTTP. If you want to query the DNS service you need to kubectl port-forward, not the HTTP (API) proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access the dashboard with localhost:8081, you have to run kubectl proxy --port 8081 from your console to setup the proxy between you localhost to the k8s apiserver.

If you want to access dashboard from apiserver directly without the local proxy, try the following url https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy (assuming your service name is kubernetes-dashboard)

You can also run kubectl port-forward svc/kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard 443, then access the dashboard with https://localhost:443